# I can not view my table that I've just created ? I coudn't figure out why

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

I'm a mac user.

So I installed mysql with homebrew, by using the following command :  brew install mysql

I started the mysql server with the following command :
 mysql.server start

I connected to mysql with the following command : mysql -uroot

I created a database called test by using the following command : 
create database test;

I created a sample table , after I connected to test database 
(after use test; command)

But when I attempt to run a query like select * from test.sampletable;

It gives me the following error :

Table 'test.sampletable' doesn't exists.

I might be missing something. Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

First select database. 

use test

Then query the table name without database name. 

Select * from sometable;

Comment: Thank you for the response :) But it does not help either. One more thing,  when I run show tables; after running use test; command, the table is not listed. :\